# Itunesconnect not able to submit app under news category without inapppruchase

Tags: ios, applet, app-store-connect

I want to submit an app under category Magazines & Newspapers, but getting following error in iTunes while submitting an app

> To submit an app with the category Magazines & Newspapers, you must offer at least one auto-renewable subscription. Set one up in In-App Purchases.

I also tried with Application presents content in Newsstand this flag in info.plist but still getting same error.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, Were you able to find a solution for that ?

Comment: No, didn't find any solution yet.